# Failed to build the PostgreSQL remote connection

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, ssh, remote-access

I have tried the method mentioned on the other answers, but only to find they all failed. What I did to the configuration are below.

1. Modified the "pg_hba.conf" file

```
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

2. Modified the "postgresql.conf" file

```
# - Connection Settings -
listen_addresses = '*'
```

3. Restart the server

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

But I still failed to build the remote connection.

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The port 5432 was open by the following command:

```
xx@xx:~$ netstat -nlt|grep :5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

And I could ping the IP address where the PostgreSQL was.

Comment: I would say "firewall", but those will generally give "timeout", not "refused".  Are you sure the host name/IP address is correct?

Comment: @jjanes I can access the server by ssh command with my account (not the DB account) of the specified IP through a specific port. So I think the IP is correct. How to check the "firewall"? I go through the "netstat" command but the default 5432 port is listening other IP's request.